How to send pi symbol (π) using selenium on windows?
I am taking selenium web driver course on test automation university. On chapter 6, the instructor is using mac and is able to send the pi symbol using the following:
public void enterPi(){
        enterText(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "p") + "=3.14");
    }

but on windows, I have to hold the alt button and press on 227 on the numpad.
I have tried both chrome and edge drivers but still not working.
This is the fuction I am using:
  public void enterText(String text){

        driver.findElement(formInput).sendKeys(text);
    }

and I tried 3 options as following with actual result I got:
option 1:
       enterText(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "227") +"=3.14");
got the following:
enter image description here
option 2:
       enterText(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.NUMPAD2, Keys.NUMPAD2, Keys.NUMPAD7) +"=3.14");
got the following:
enter image description here
option 3: doesn't use the enterText function
       new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.ALT).sendKeys("227").perform();
enter image description here

what about "π" directly (or "\u03C0") (sorry, I do not use selenium, that would be a plain Java solution)

The best way to do this is by using Robot class which can be used to perform system level interaction using key combinations. Please try to use the below code for the same. You can use the below code to enter π in the required field.
    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element"));// Provide the identifier of the text box or field
    we.click();// perform a click operation to confirm the cursor is on the particular text input field
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

